# Google Chrome performance: Linux vs Windows

Tags: linux, windows, performance, css, google-chrome

I've done website with some expensive CSS3 effect - a lot of text shadows and animation. When I run this site in Google Chrome 37 on Ubuntu 14.04 FPS counter shows about 5 FPS. The same site in the same Chrome version on Windows 7 run at ~16 FPS.

Why is so much difference in FPS between this two versions of Chrome?

Comment: Is the hardware for the two systems comparable?  Obviously, on a slower computer, the page will run more sluggishly.

Comment: If it is the same computer than it is possibly graphics driver related - some video cards are pretty poor performance wise in Linux if you're getting poor FPS try updating the whole graphics stack (Kernel version, MESA, Xorg etc.) and see if that boost your FPS.

Try using Firefox it has some built in debugging tools that might help and tends to have a lot better plugins for web developers than chrome does (at least last I looked).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the observed behavior is that Chrome has put a lot of work optimizing drivers for major operating systems and it in fact runs slower on Linux.

Maybe, using Wine 5 you would be able to run the chrome windows version, and do some benchmarks and let the world know of the difference.